# How to go initial state after onClick function fired in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made `copy to clipboard` component. It's working fine. But i want to make it  goes to initial state after copied the text. That's mean before `onClick` event it will show on hover "Copy to Clipboard" and when it clicked, it will show "Copied to clipboard" and goes to initial state (Copy to Clipboard) and if i click again then `onClick` event will be fire again.

[Here is my working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-star-ol9ft)

```
  copyToClipboard = async e => {
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(this.textContent);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    this.setState({ copied: true });
  };

  initRef = c => (this.textContent = c);

  render() {
    const { copied } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="positioning">
        <p onClick={this.copyToClipboard} ref={this.initRef}>
          chonchol@gmail.com
        </p>

        {copied === false ? (
          <p className="success">Copy to Clipboard</p>
        ) : (
          <p className="success">Copied to Clipboard</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AsafAviv I need copy text multiple times. Say you have multiple `p` then i need to copy when click on one `p` and if i clicked on other `p` then that will be copy also.

Comment: It's bad practice to provide a link to a code sandbox without including the problematic part of the code in the question as well. The question should be self-contained with enough information to be answerable without needing to go  to external links. Any external links should be supplementary to the question and not necessary to answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple thing.

When you leave mouse from email, it makes you always back to `copy to clipboard`

```
<p
   onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ copied: false })}
   onClick={this.copyToClipboard}
   ref={this.initRef}

> chonchol@gmail.com </p>
```

Comment: if i have multiple `p` tag then what will happen? is it copy if i click on any text?

Comment: Sure. The copy function has nothing to do with this. This is just a code that has to do with your status message. But if you want to make multiple `p`tag, you should change `copyToCliboard` function.

Answer (score 0):

well i added a function to fire on mouse enter ! so if u state is true it will set to false!

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class CopyClipboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textContent = null;
    this.state = {
      copied: false
    };
  }

  copyToClipboard = async e => {
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(this.textContent);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    this.setState({ copied: true });
  };
  copy = () => {
    if (this.state.copied) {
      this.setState({ copied: false });
    }
  };
  initRef = c => (this.textContent = c);

  render() {
    const { copied } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="positioning" onMouseEnter={this.copy}>
        <p onClick={this.copyToClipboard} ref={this.initRef}>
          chonchol@gmail.com
        </p>
        {copied === false ? (
          <p className="success">Copy to Clipboard</p>
        ) : (
          <p className="success">Copied to Clipboard</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<CopyClipboard />, rootElement);
```

Comment: if i have multiple `p` tag then what will happen? is it copy if i click on any text?

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/adoring-merkle-wz7jf)

Just set state.copied to 'false' after a desired timeout.

```
copyToClipboard = async e => {
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(this.textContent);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    this.setState({ copied: true });
  };

  clickHandler = e => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ copied: false });
    }, 2000);
    this.copyToClipboard(e);
  };

  initRef = c => (this.textContent = c);

  render() {
    const { copied } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="positioning">
        <p onClick={this.clickHandler} ref={this.initRef}>
          chonchol@gmail.com
        </p>
        {copied === false ? (
          <p className="success">Copy to Clipboard</p>
        ) : (
          <p className="success">Copied to Clipboard</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: For the benefit of future readers as well as people who don't trust links that lead outside of SO can you embed the code in the answer?

Answer (score -1):

You just need to set the state after a delay.

```
this.setState({ copied: true });

setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({ copied: false });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: if i have multiple `p` tag then what will happen? is it copy if i click on any text?

Comment: In that case you have to use this component in multiple places. Considering you are going to put that in main App component for example: 

`<CopyClipboard text="Your Text to copy" /> <CopyClipboard text="Your another text" />`

You make that component reusable and use it as much as you want.